# Hown can I remove FreeCAD from Accessibility on macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, mac

Recently my macOS ask me if I would like that FreeCAD controls my computer. Accidentally, I answered yes, but now I cannot remove it from Security and Privacy preferences.

[image: Screenshot of Security and Privacy]

Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks you very much.

Comment: Your arrow points to the enable/disable checkbox which I see is disabled, so right now it doesn't have any permissions & so is 'safe'. It's hard for me to tell, as I don't use dark mode, but is the item also highlighted? If so, that should let you then remove it with the - button.

Comment: I can't enable/disable the checkbox and I can't hit the - button when I select it either.

Previously appeared, for example, Photoshop i could enable/disable the checkbox and I could remove it using - button.

Later I'll try to record a video with the problem for better understanding.

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you unlock again, bottom left? It will relock every time you exit the prefs.

Comment: If you can't check/uncheck or remove from the list even when authenticated as an administrator, that leads me to believe that the app may have done something (on purpose or inadvertantly) to prevent what you are trying to do. I would email the app's support address and see what they have to say. Updating or reinstalling might also be a good idea.

Comment: Following add screencast of problem

https://youtu.be/mPBkCryYC5k

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the Accessibility list by running the following command in the terminal:

```
$ tccutil reset Accessibility
```